# How to load Nearest Shopping Cart Price Rule in Cart Page of magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to display nearest shopping cart price rule in shopping cart based on the cart subtotal.

Ex: If my shopping cart subtotal is $10, then i want to display shopping cart rule which is valid for $15(or nearest).

Please help.